# Domdocument encoding

Tags: php, html, encoding, domdocument

The Question is about Domdocument encoding, when i open an HTML string that contain UTF-8 contents, with `loadHTML` method and do my changes , when i want to save it , into a variable with `saveHTML` and then put it into the Database, All the Characters was changed to something like this :

```
&#1585;&#1608;&#1588; &#1585;&#1575; &#1575;&#1605;&#1578;&#1581;&#1575;&#1606
```

and i can't read it. what is this characters and any suggestion to prevent this change  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are not parsing the html properly. Read this for more info http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php